# Using upper bound information in graph search

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

I am using [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) (A-Star) to search a graph. A* algorithm takes advantage of the information $h(x)$, which is a lower bound of the distance between a vertex $x$ and the destination vertex.
In other words: $h(x) \leq d(x,dest)$, where $x$ is a some vertex and $dest$ is the destination vertex.

Besides the lower bound, I happen to know an upper bound for $d(x,dest)$. I was wondering if I could use this information to somehow speed up the A* search.

I appreciate any ideas that you might have. Thank you.

Comment: It of course depends on how good of an upperbound is provided.  For example, if your algorithm always outputs the upperbound $n$ (where $n$ is the number of vertices of the graph), then it will be useless.

Comment: My upperbound is better than the trival one. Do you have an idea of how to incorporate it into the A* algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The following may well have occurred to you already, but for completeness ...)

If I've fully understood the information that you have (and in context of [A* pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode) as you cited):

1. At any given time, the set `openset` holds the nodes that are candidates to step off to. Each of these nodes has an `f_score[]` value, which is the lower bound you refer to in your question.

   (Intuitively, if I'm using A* to find the shortest path on a simple four-connected grid, my lower bound distance is the 'as the crow flies' distance, which is a lower bound to the 'follow the grid' distance.)
2. The condition you add is that, from another source, you know that the distance from $x$ to $dest$ should be no more than some upper bound.

Consequently when adding nodes to the open set (`openset`), you could ignore nodes that have a distance to $dest$ that are greater than your supplied upper bound.  As in

```
upperboundDistToDest = (Calculation of upper bound)

(... then in the appropriate place ...)

if neighbor not in openset and dist(neighbour, dest) < upperboundDistToDest 
    add neighbor to openset
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I didn't think about it. It's a cool idea. I wonder if this is the best use of the upper bound information I have. In your answer, I assume that by dist(neighbour,dest) you mean my_lower_bound(neighbour,dest).